# Should I stop including useful tips with my answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I tend to answer mainly in VBA and every now and then people have an error which highlights that they haven't learnt some of the useful basics/ good practices yet.

As well as providing working code and explaining the changes I made, I also mention some best practices that might help them/ others avoid future errors.

This morning I noticed a comment on one of my posts saying that this type of answer belongs on Code Review than SO.

As far as I'm concerned, any helpful answer that is useful in any way has a place on SO. I certainly would have benefitted from coming across an answer like that when I was starting out.

I can appreciate that you typically see this kind of thing more on Code Review, but is there a reason you *shouldn't* be doing this on SO? Especially because OPs error clearly shows that they are lacking the basics.

The comment/answer in question is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43946661/2859347

---

**Update**

As per Martijn's answer below, my original answer was deleted. The post has since been edited (see [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349138/should-i-stop-including-useful-tips-with-my-answers/349141?noredirect=1#comment473627_349141)) so for full context see the revision history (revision 3).

Comment: Meh.  The post did not answer the question, that's a reason for somebody to speak up.  You can easily do both, answer the question in the first paragraph, elaborate in the rest.

Comment: @HansPassant - is that to say that providing working code and commentary around that code doesn't qualify as "answering the question" ?

Comment: No, not really.  You rewrote his code but did not point out the specific mistake in his code.  High odds he would make the exact same mistake again tomorrow.  It will probably take him a couple of years to get up to your skill level, programmers tend to learn good coding habits from making enough mistakes.  Nothing wrong with the advice, just make sure you help him get past the speed-bump he's suffering from today.

Comment: I do note that the comments were posted on an answer that **only** gave the extra tips, you didn't actually address the question. At this point your post is far less useful. Don't post additional information in a separate answer where none is needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. How well do you know VBA? Some of those comments were best practices, others were directly helping to avoid the specific issue. For example, `.Value` avoids OP's error when pasting. Also the code provides a different and complete solution. I can't see who deleted my answer, but it's been voted as useful twice and also OP commented suggesting they possibly found it useful. I hardly think it was necessary to *delete* it. Even the original commenter (who does understand VBA very well) notes that some of the answer does address the question!

Comment: @CallumDA: Put the answer **first**. The rest is icing. Your first line clearly indicates you were posting additional information, not an answer.

Comment: @CallumDA: if you hid the actual answer in the post, you did a terrible job of communicating what the actual problem was.

Comment: FWIW - The actual answer to the question (that you can't `Select` a cell in a worksheet that isn't active) is only mentioned once - as a comment to the question.  Both answers fail to mention that as the cause, but probably could have done so - and then that would have led into mentioning that that is one of the reasons why we keep telling people that using `Select` and `Activate` are bad practice.

Comment: @CallumDA The advice you gave to OP is actually really useful - but you posted it in a place where it is not appreciated (and that's OK). How about you join us at https://codereview.stackexchange.com and share your knowledge where it is much more appreciated?

Answer (score 86):

You left out context here; your post *didn't address the question*. Your post starts with:

> Further to the good answers and comments already provided, you can neaten up your code a lot.

followed by a code review.

The feedback left on your answer is not complaining that you gave extra tips to improve the code. Your answer consists **only** of a code review, and the commenter is correct that you should have stuck to commenting instead.

That's because your post is not an answer to the question when it only consists of feedback that is tangential to the actual problem posted. Because of this I've deleted your post.

Had you actually posted an answer and then *added* your commentary to that answer, then that would have been very welcome.

Comment: This doesn't really *answer* the question, it is a answer-review for the original questioner. :P

Comment: @gz.: the very last paragraph answers the generic question, but the specifics are what lead to the question in the first place and that context matters hugely.

Comment: If OP were to use the code provided in my answer his problem would be solved. How can you argue it's not an answer?

Comment: @CallumDA - OP is asking: `Can anybody give me a sense of why I'd be receiving a 1004 error on the following code?` Your answer does **not** address that question. Your answer is a set of unrelated guidelines and a code dump without any explanation. So your answer is for sure **not** answering the question.

Comment: Personally, I was hoping to get a good answer to this question, yet this answer contradicts others' advice about answering the question first and foremost. CallumDA emphasized the he also thought the context justified adding additional information to other's answers. I have seen many answers that rely on other answers without giving a full standalone solution themselves, but for which limited Markdown and space in comments would not be sufficient. They can still be good answers and deserve a place beyond comments. "Further to the good answers" is sufficient reference for continuation I think.

Comment: All that answer needs is a tiny little edit that merely explains how the provided snippet fixes OP's specific problem. [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43946661/revisions). And now the answer can't be undeleted, because it was mod-deleted. I don't think the treatment of that answer was completely fair. @CallumDA should indeed have provided an explanation for his snippet right from the start, but all this could have been avoided with one single comment requesting a tiny little explanation of how that snippet fixes OP's problem. Can it be undeleted now?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: undeleted, thanks for editing!

Comment: Phew! You just saved me from a couple of broken teeth, that mug sure looks crunchy!

Answer (score 13):

The start of an *Answer* should always actually answer the question, after that I think asides are okay.

I too like including observations, whimiscal comments, and code style pointers in my responses. Someone arriving at the site via search won't want to read a list of pointers about the original questioner's code though, so at least make it brief and easy to skip at the end.

Lots of other people seem to use comments on the question itself for style problems, which in many ways is worse. When there are lots of commments the top answer may be pushed below the fold, and despite the small font they're rather hard to skim past.

I know that editing a question for coding style reasons is discouraged, but for a generic question that does remove the distractions of odd variables names the questioner happened to pick and so on.

Comment: The site hides comments behind a 'see more' link to prevent answers being pushed below the fold. Using an answer just to post style review comments is not a viable alternative to using comments.

Comment: Not as bad as people using the comments section for "hints" to the answer or even the actual solution itself. Gah.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Two things, 1) if I feel that I would have to spend an hour or three researching the exact problem (e.g. duplicating the situation and debugging myself) in order to provide a complete answer, but which I'm pretty sure can be resolved through a one line "try X" comment (e.g. "put a debug statement there, is that line even being called?" and the answer turns out to be "no" and the Asker subsequently realizes why) then its not an answer.  2) If the comment *is* an answer, ask the commenter to **make** it an answer so you can upvote it.

Comment: @Draco18s: 1) That's fine; that's a request for clarification. 2) I do, multiple times per day. It's getting tiring.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition 1) probably wasn't the best example, but I've certainly made suggestions where I was like, "Well, my first thought is to try doing X and seeing if that works."  I don't *know* it'll work (thus isn't an answer) but if it *does* now it *can be an answer* because there's a known alteration that results in the desired behavior and it becomes easier to work out why that change was needed. 2) Heh.

Comment: @Draco18s: Knowing your answer is right isn't necessarily a pre-requisite. We have downvotes for a reason: to tell you that it's wrong. We can't downvote comments. By all means ask someone to try something, but comments aren't a chatroom: don't use them to engage in a conversation with hints and tips. Either give an answer, or don't! If you're not sure, don't.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Sure, but I'd rather answer with "this is because X you need to do Y" rather than "have you tried Y?" If Y works, then I know it was because of X, but if Y doesn't work, then I might be flummoxed or have a different suggestion Z.

Comment: @Draco18s: Then you may be happier in a chatroom format.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Oh, probably. And I do do minecraft modding help on the forge forums. Dozens of repeat questions (there's one issue I can spot with two words from the title: "custom crop." Problem: user registered their item (referencing the block) before creating and registering the block)

Answer (score 6):

personally, my use of SO is augmented heavily by google, so the OP may be asking a more specific question than me / the googler. I've found a lot of answers this way and I have to skip over the selected answer to find someone who provided a larger context which captures my use-case. Also, this answer typically has more up-votes than the "correct" answer. So I would say more information is good.

Comment: The extra information is good, so long as the answer actually answers the question posed by the OP.

Comment: Also @hpassant above says " programmers tend to learn good coding habits from making enough mistakes" which seems wrong to me.  Programmers do make a lot of mistakes :-).  And that teaches us.. mostly to avoid them. But we learn good coding habits much more from seeing it done right.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I often scroll down on questions because late answers often contain various tips and tricks and tangentially related information.

Stack Overflow doesn't like this because - as said - those answers do not *directly* answer the question, but I prefer utility over blind following of the rules.

Comment: On older questions the late answers also tend to provide more current-generation approaches to a solution and those can be far more valuable than existing accepted/top voted solutions which have been sitting around for years collecting upvotes. One should definitely not neglect to read through them.